# python 3.4.3 f.write is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following is Snippet of my program:

```
with open(completepathname,'wb') as f:              
    print ('file opened')
    print(f)
    while True:
           print('receiving data...')
           print('hello')

           data = send_receive_protocol.recv_msg(conn)
           #print('hi')
           print(data)
           if not data:
                print('printing1')
                break

           print('printing')
           data1=data.encode()
           print(data1)
           f.write(data1)#write to file
           f.close()
```

output prints correctly to the console, but if I go open up the file it's blank. If I delete the file and execute my program again, the file is created but still is empty

Comment: why do you `f.close()` the file? `with` will take care of that.

Comment: The obvious problem is the `f.close()`; since this is an endless loop, you probably want to *flush* instead. Use `f.flush()` to flush the OS buffer.

Comment: Works for me: this ``f.close()`` should indeed be ``f.flush()``, but at least ``f.close()`` flushes the buffer too.  If I run it as pasted, send a single bunch of data, and then block in the second ``recv_msg()``, then I see the data in the (now-closed) file.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet works as expected:

```
with open('test.txt', 'wb') as f:              
    while True:
           data = 'test-data'

           if not data:
                break

           data1 = data.encode('hex')
           f.write(data1)
           f.flush()
```

You should be careful not to `.close()` a file-like object and then continue to attempt to write to it. If you need to ensure the output is written right away, use `.flush()`.